# W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field

Tags: android

Could someone explain this logcat message? (and suggest a way to remove it?)

```
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 54 (ADD)
in Landroid/graphics/PorterDuff$Mode;
```

(Note: I have no idea wha's causing it, so I don't know what else portion of the app to inspect, and I am using a SurfaceView to draw VectorDrawableCompat on the Canvas)

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could someone explain this logcat message?

You have code that is conditionally [using `PorterDuff.Mode.ADD`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html). For whatever reason, that does not exist in the framework on your Android device. That is rather odd, as that field should have existed since API Level 1, if the documentation is correct.

> and suggest a way to remove it?

In general, you don't. This is a warning, not an error. You will get lots of these warnings, any time that you are using code that will use newer methods and classes on newer devices but gracefully degrade to avoid them on older devices. This approach is standard fare for Android development, whether you do the graceful degradation yourself or get it as part of an Android Support library.

Comment: True, the warning doesn't show up on higher APIs (like API 23), thank you for your help